# Formula to add numbers on a date and turn to a specific day

Tags: excel, excel-2007

In cell A1 i have stock date. In cell A2 is the ship date which is every Saturday on the same week. What is the formula so that any date in cell A1 will turn to Saturday on the same week of cell A2?

Answer (score 2):

Try this formula

```
=A1+7-WEEKDAY(A1)
```